# Console.ReadLine return null in powershell

Tags: powershell, .net-core, raspberry-pi, windows-iot-core-10

I'm connecting to my .NET Core 2 app deployed to Raspberry Pi va PowerShell - the problem is that Console.ReadLine() is not waiting for user input but returns null. The same program in SSH works good? How can I make it work in PowerShell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems a problem about powershell on Windows IoT Core. Even a blank windows iot core console application in C++, **cin** also appears the same issue. I have reported this issue via Feedback Hub App(https://aka.ms/AA3cmsf). Please wait patiently till it is fixed.So at the moment, you can use SSH instead.

Comment: Is this issue solved ? I'm still facing this issue on Win10IoTCore powershell.

Comment: @KeshavaGN, this issue has not been fixed until now. I have tested on 17763. But it can work when you connect the device via putty.

Comment: Yes Michael, I observed that, But the same issue is observed when I run the app on CMD on device. Do you think it's the same issue ?

Comment: also, is there any alternatives for reading from console on IoTCore?

Comment: @KeshavaGN, i have said that you can use putty to connect the device and then run the console app, it will read from console in putty.

Comment: Yes @Michael, Can you confirm if the same issue is observed when the app run on cmd.exe on IoT device?

Comment: @KeshavaGN, sorry i;m confused how you run the app on cmd.exe? Did you mean run the command in device portal(processes->run commands)?

Comment: On the device, run commands option. On that I tried running the app. I'm seeing same behavior as powershell.